# Yii2 Twitter Bootstrap badge color not changing: badge-success badge-danger e.t.c classes not found

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Yii2 **Twitter Bootstrap** *badge* colors not changing.

> In browser source i cant find **badge-success**, **badge-danger** e.t.c
> classes.

**This is my PHP code**

```
<?= Html::tag('span',
    $model->enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
    [
      'class' => 'badge badge-' . ($model->enabled ? 'success' : 'danger')
    ])
?>
```

This is result of code.

[image]

## The browser source code

[image]

## This is css code

[image]

Comment: you should use `label label-success` rather than the `badge badge-success` as it  is only available in bootstrap4, apparently you are using bootstrap3

Comment: @AaronYordanyan If you have another question, ask it as another question instead of editing old one.

Comment: @rob006 i cant write new question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`badge-success`, `badge-danger` and others are available since Bootstrap 4. You need to use [`yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4) package or implement these styles for badges yourself (see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/MarcosBL/pen/uomCD)).